# Is using List methods within a map() not viable in Python?

Tags: python, list, mapping, higher-order-functions

I have a project to work on where I'm not allowed to use for nor while cycles. I can only make use of map(), filter(), reduce and such higher order fucntions.
I have a solid idea of what i have to do, but when I tried to use the .insert() method within a map, it returns a NoneType. And if I use list(), it returns a list of None types.

```
map(lambda x, y: x.insert(y, info), double_list, size)
```

This was what I was trying to do, being the double list a list of equal lists and size a certain range. Something like [[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]].
The idea was to insert a certain object (a string) into all the sublists, but in different positions. For example, if I wanted to insert to place the number 5 into all of them, the output should look like [[5,1,2,3], [1,5,2,3], [1,2,5,3]].
With a for cycle this would be a piece of cake, but with the restrictions, I'm having a real hard time.

Comment: "but when I tried to use the .insert() method within a map, it returns a NoneType. And if I use list(), it returns a list of None types." *of course*. That is what those methods *always* return. Those methods modify the list object *in-place*, and conventionally, will return `None`. You *shouldn't be mixing mutation and functional programming constructs like `map`, `filer`, and `reduce`. Those should use pure-functions, with no side-effects

Comment: You'll notice, `double_list` *will be affected* by using `list(map(lambda x, y: x.insert(y, info), double_list, size))`, but again, *you shouldn't be doing that*. Don't use `map`/`filter` (or list comprehensions, etc) for side-effects!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like

```py
info = 5
double_list = [[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]]

print([sl[:i] + [info] + sl[i:] for i, sl in enumerate(double_list)])
```

or if you can't use for in a comprehension for whatever reason.

```py
map(lambda v: v[1][:v[0]] + [info] + v[1][v[0]:], enumerate(double_list))
```